# Intellisense for D in VS Code

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, d

I'm using the **code-d** extension. Auto-completion works for the standard library, but not for installed modules. The same vibe-d. And also, you can easily write a call to a non-existent method or a similar error, and at the same time it will not be highlighted as an error.

Am I not setting something up correctly, or is it just a raw ecosystem for the language? In addition to **VS Code**, I tried **Dexed**, but it seems to be much worse.

Comment: hi, I'd recommend opening an issue on https://github.com/Pure-D/code-d - disclaimer I'm the author, but it's the most used extension for D by install count at least. Additionally you might get a better experience if you let code-d install a beta/nightly version of serve-d by going into the user settings and changing d.servedReleaseChannel to beta or nightly - then reload the window using Ctrl-Shift-P -> reload window

Answer (score 1):

I use VSCode and code-d and it does work. But occasionally I have to build once first, before it will recognize the dependency modules for autocomplete/intellisense.

Note that WebFreak is the author of code-d, so probably follow their advice too.